# Why am I getting a Type error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str, while calling a function and passing a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm finding my footing in data science and I came across an issue, I am creating a function that performs some computation for a hypothetical mobile subscription company

I created a dictionary as seen below:

```py
mobile_sub = {'minutes_used': 200,
              'minutes_included': 200,
              'texts_used': 200,
              'texts_included': 200,
              'monthly_plan': 10,
              'cost_per_minute': 0.03,
              'cost_per_sms': 0.001,
              'vat_tax': 0.14}
```

then the function for the computation :

```py
def evaluateCharges(input_data=[]):
    minutes_used = input_data['minutes_used']
    texts_used = input_data['texts_used']
   
    # Performing different actions based on the conditions indicated in the question.
    if minutes_used > 200:
        aditional_minutes = minutes_used-minutes_included
        basecharge = monthly_plan + (aditional_minutes * 0.03)
        
    if texts_used > 200 :
        aditional_texts = texts_used - texts_included
        basecharge = monthly_plan + (aditional_texts * 0.001)
        
    VAT_TAX = basecharge * vat_tax
    basecharge += VAT_TAX
    

    # We can choose to format our basecharg  2dp
    finalCharges =  round(basecharge, 2) 

    # We then create a string with 
    output_string = "Dear Customer, below are the charges on your account : \n Minutes Used: ' +  str(minutes_used) + '\n Texts Used: ' + str(texts_used) + '\n Additional Minutes: ' + str(aditional_minutes) + '\n Additional Texts: ' + str(aditional_texts) + '\n Basecharge: $' + str(basecharge) + '\n Tax Applied: 14% \n Total Charges: $' +  str(taxApplied)"

    # the returning our output string
    return print(output_string)
```

## Then calling our function and passing our dictionary

```py
evaluateCharges(input_data=[ 250, 185])
```

This is where I got the error :TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str, how can I avoid it?

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-a618d565246b> in <module>()
     36 # Then calling our function and passing our dictionary
     37 
---> 38 evaluateCharges(input_data=[ 250, 185])

<ipython-input-25-a618d565246b> in evaluateCharges(input_data)
      7     based on the values received.
      8     '''
----> 9     minutes_used = input_data['minutes_used']
     10     texts_used = input_data['texts_used']
     11 

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Just a heads up, `print()` returns `None`. So by doing `return print(output_string)` your function will end up returning `None`. Also, using mutable defaults is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Input data is supposed to be a map, but you are passing in [250, 185]. Then, when you index it with `minutes_used = input_data['minutes_used']`, it's telling you that you can't index it with a string.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a two element list to the evaluateCharges function which is why the error is occurring. In python, you access list indices with the syntax `mylist[index]` where index is an integer. Here, you are trying to pass the strings `minutes_used` and `texts_used` as indices to the list called `input_data`. I think you intend `input_data` to be a dictionary instead of a list. It looks like you can get the desired behavior from passing your dictionary in instead:

```
mobile_sub = {'minutes_used': 200, 'minutes_included': 200, 'texts_used': 200, 'texts_included' : 200, 'monthly_plan': 10, 'cost_per_minute': 0.03 , 'cost_per_sms': 0.001, 'vat_tax': 0.14 }
evaluateCharges(input_data=mobile_sub)
```

Following this, your default value for `input_data` should be a dictionary instead of a list.

Edit: As pointed out by @ddejohn there really shouldn't be a default value at all for this function.

Comment: The default value should be neither. Using mutable defaults results in unintended behavior.

Comment: Agreed, good point

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions and assistance, let me try correct and implement